# XML Schema invalid - [s4s-elt-invalid-content.1:]

Tags: xml, schema

I'm having problems with validing my XML Schema. My schema kod:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        <xsd:element name="colection">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="author" type="TypAuthor" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xsd:element name="books" type="TypBooks"/>
                    <xsd:element name="films" type="TypFilms"/>
                    <xsd:element name="copyright" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:complexType name="TypAuthor">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="surname" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="gender" type="TypSex"/>
                <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="study" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="semester" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="group" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:simpleType name="TypSex">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="male"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="female"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>

        <xsd:complexType name="TypBooks">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="book" type="TypBook" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:complexType name="TypBook">
            <xsd:attribute name="nr" type="TypNr" />
            <xsd:attribute name= "lang" type="TypLang"/>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="author" type="TypAuthor2"/>
                <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="pages" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:integer"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:complexType name="TypAuthor2">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:attribute name="country" type="TypCountry2" use="required"/>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>    
        </xsd:complexType>


        <xsd:simpleType name="TypCountry2">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="USA"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="PL"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="UK"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="FR"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>

        <xsd:simpleType name="TypNr">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                <xsd:maxInclusive value="5"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>

        <xsd:simpleType name="TypLang">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="pl"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="en"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="fr"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>

        <xsd:complexType name="TypFilms">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="film" type="TypFilm" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:complexType name="TypFilm">
            <xsd:attribute name="nr" type="TypNr" />
            <xsd:attribute name= "lang" type="TypLang"/>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="director" type="TypDirector"/>
                <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="stars" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="TypDirector">
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:attribute name="country" type="TypCountry2" use="required"/>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

The error message I'm getting is this:

**s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'TypBook' is invalid. Element 'complexContent' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.**

s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'TypFilm' is invalid. Element 'complexContent' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Do you have any suggestion? I need to send this valid schema to my Profesor before 11pm. Please HELP!!

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's a very poor error message, but as Larsson says, the attributes must be defined after the content.

If you can't find a rule like this in the prose of the spec, it's probably in the schema for schema documents, which is a normative part of the spec.

Comment: I had the same error message. It worked when I defined the `attribute` elements **AFTER** the `sequence` element indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is due to the sequence coming before the attributes, try this:
I did spend a couple of minutes trying too google a source for this rule but did not find much. However at the [`w3Shools complex type docs`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_complextype.asp) the syntax is specified with attributes last. Not very explicit though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema id="XMLSchema1"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xsd:element name="colection">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="author" type="TypAuthor" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="books" type="TypBooks"/>
        <xsd:element name="films" type="TypFilms"/>
        <xsd:element name="copyright" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="TypAuthor">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xsd:element name="surname" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="gender" type="TypSex"/>
      <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:integer"/>
      <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="study" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="semester" type="xsd:integer"/>
      <xsd:element name="group" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="TypSex">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="male"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="female"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:complexType name="TypBooks">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="book" type="TypBook" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="TypBook">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="author" type="TypAuthor2"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="pages" type="xsd:integer"/>
      <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:integer"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="nr" type="TypNr" />
    <xsd:attribute name= "lang" type="TypLang"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="TypAuthor2">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="country" type="TypCountry2" use="required"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:simpleType name="TypCountry2">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="USA"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="PL"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="UK"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="FR"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="TypNr">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
      <xsd:maxInclusive value="5"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="TypLang">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="pl"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="en"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="fr"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:complexType name="TypFilms">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="film" type="TypFilm" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="TypFilm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="director" type="TypDirector"/>
      <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:integer"/>
      <xsd:element name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="stars" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="nr" type="TypNr" />
    <xsd:attribute name= "lang" type="TypLang"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="TypDirector">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="country" type="TypCountry2" use="required"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of defining the xsd element.
For example, considering the following scenario

```
<xsd:complexType name="Element-A>
  <xsd:attribute name="attribute1" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
  <xsd:attribute name="attribute2" type="xsd:int" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now, in this case, if you want to add an  attribute, you can add ONLY IN THE BEGINNING.
Also, you have to surround it with the  attribute. So, the above code will translate in the following:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Element-A>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="element1" type="f1:elementDefinition"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:attribute name="attribute1" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
   <xsd:attribute name="attribute2" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="elementDefinition">
   <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

The above code makes sure that you have a list in your "Element-A" of the type "elementDefinition" referenced by element1 in the xsd.